# NSTextView syntax highlighting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syntax-highlighting, nstextview

I'm working on a Cocoa text editor which uses an NSTextView. Is it possible to change the color of certain portions of the text?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should add your controller as the delegate of the `NSTextStorage` object of the `NSTextView` (`[textView textStorage]`) and then implement the delegate method `‑textStorageDidProcessEditing:`. This is called whenever the text changes.

In the delegate method you need to get the current `NSTextStorage` object from the text view using the `-textStorage` method of `NSTextView`. `NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSAttributedString` and contains the attributed contents of the view.

Your code must then parse the string and apply coloring to whatever ranges of text are interesting to you. You apply color to a range using something like this, which will apply a yellow color to the whole string:

```
//get the range of the entire run of text
NSRange area = NSMakeRange(0, [textStorage length]);

//remove existing coloring
[textStorage removeAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName range:area];

//add new coloring
[textStorage addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                    value:[NSColor yellowColor] 
                    range:area];
```

How you parse the text is up to you. `NSScanner` is a useful class to use when parsing text.

Note that this method is by no means the most efficient way of handling syntax coloring. If the documents you are editing are very large you will most likely want to consider offloading the parsing to a separate thread and/or being clever about which sections of text are reparsed.

Comment: This is a bit old, but how would I implement `-textStorageDidProcessEditing:` into the delegate?

Comment: Just like any other delegate method. Look up the [signature of the method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTextStorageDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008627-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3) in the docs and place it in your delegate object's implementation. Make sure your delegate object is set as the delegate of the `NSTextStorage`.

Comment: @RobKeniger, I think the controller needs to be the NSTextStorage's delegate, not the NSTextView's delegate. Is that right? That's my experience and what the comment suggests, but it contradicts and makes confusing the first two paragraphs of the answer.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of the answer below, in my case assigning a delegate to NSTextStorage seems to break the `contentSize` property of my UITextView. Has anyone else experienced this behavior? (Xcode 6.3.1 / iOS 8.3)

Answer (score 13):

[Rob Keniger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220684/901641) is good, but for someone looking for a more concrete example, here's a short syntax highlighter I wrote that should highlight RegEx template syntax. I want `\` to be gray, with the character immediately following them to be black. I want `$` to be red, with a digit character immediately following the `$` to also be red. Everything else should be black. Here's my solution:

I made a template highlighter class, with a header that looks like this:

```
@interface RMETemplateHighlighter : NSObject <NSTextStorageDelegate>

@end
```

I initialize it in the nib file as an object and hook it up to my view controller with an outlet. In `awakeFromNib` of the view controller, I have this (where `replacer` is my `NSTextView` outlet and `templateHighlighter` is the outlet for the class above):

```
self.replacer.textStorage.delegate = self.templateHighlighter;
```

And my implementation looks like this:

```
- (void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = notification.object;
    NSString *string = textStorage.string;
    NSUInteger n = string.length;
    [textStorage removeAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName range:NSMakeRange(0, n)];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c == '\\') {
            [textStorage addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor lightGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
            i++;
        } else if (c == '$') {
            NSUInteger l = ((i < n - 1) && isdigit([string characterAtIndex:i+1])) ? 2 : 1;
            [textStorage addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(i, l)];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

So there you go, a fully working example. There were a few details that had me tripped up for ~10 minutes, like the fact that you have to take the string out of textStorage to access the individual characters... maybe this save other people a few minutes.

Comment: This works great for syntax highlighting, but in my case also seems to break the `contentSize` of my UITextView. More specifically, the `contentSize` seems to always be the width of the UITextView x the height of  a single line.

Comment: @carloe: This is an OS X solution... you're mentioning `UITextView` (not **NS** `TextView`) so I assume you're working with iOS. There may be small differences between the APIs... what is best on OS X may not be best on iOS.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare you are right, my bad! I should learn to read the titles. For what it is worth, I solved my issue with the UITextView by setting `allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;` on the layout manager.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to start by reading the [CocoaDev page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ImplementSyntaxHighlighting) about Syntax Highlighing. A lot of people have come with solutions for various goals.

If you want to perform source code syntax highlighting, I suggest you to take a look at the [UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument](http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm) from [Uli Kusterer](http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/home.htm).

Comment: Lol, never downloaded so many samples from 1 single site, great!

Comment: the mentioned tool is now on github: [UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument](https://github.com/uliwitness/UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can give the `NSTextView` an `NSAttributedString`, and some of the stuff you can do with the attributed string is apply colors to certain subranges of the string.

Or you can [search on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=cocoa+syntax+highlighting) and see that a lot of people have done stuff with this before.

I'd probably recommend using [OkudaKit](http://parsekit.com/okudakit/).

Comment: it seems OkudaKit is not longer in development