# How can I loop through individual NSStrings in a NSString? (Syntax highlighting/coloring)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I'm making a Brainfuck (programming language) IDE, and I'm stuck with the syntax coloring.

I want to predefine a `NSDictionary` with substrings, and loop through them and 
return an array with (or loop through) the ranges of the substrings in a given string.

**Example:**

```
NSMutableDictionary* keywords = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[keywords setObject:[self colorForSymbol:0] forKey:@"<"];

[keywords setObject:[self colorForSymbol:0] forKey:@">"];

[keywords setObject:[self colorForSymbol:1] forKey:@"+"];

[keywords setObject:[self colorForSymbol:1] forKey:@"-"];
```

And then for each symbol, I would color all the matching `NSRanges` using the `NSTextStorage` of an `NSTextView`.

What I need to know is how to use `NSScanner` or something similar for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218415/nstextview-syntax-highlighting) will probably help with the mechanics of hooking syntax colouring into `NSTextView`.

To do the actual tokenisation you should have a look at [`NSScanner`](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCEQFjAB&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html&ei=9Fn1Tcf0IYLGvQP57YXgBg&usg=AFQjCNF8LPTe_9Gb_rPRbWofVDOibPSuJw). You will probably need to parse the text in multiple passes, for each of the tokens. You could also use regular expressions, using something like [RegexKitLite](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/&ei=01n1TfmlDor2vwPNubG4Bg&usg=AFQjCNEhXNhdUjaczT5ffylrnPWueZsmRQ).

Here is a simple demonstration of NSScanner:

```
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"A string <with> <tokens>"];

NSString* token = @"<";

NSMutableArray* ranges = [NSMutableArray array];

while(![scanner isAtEnd])
{
    [scanner scanUpToString:token intoString:nil];
    if(![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        NSRange tokenRange = NSMakeRange([scanner scanLocation], 1);
        [ranges addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:tokenRange]];
        [scanner scanString:token intoString:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: RegexKitLite just wouldn't get the matches, and I don't know how to use NSScanner in this case.

Comment: Post your code. RegexKitLite will definitely match the tokens. I'll update the answer with more NSScanner detail.